# SQL Errors in SSIS

Tags: sql, excel, ssis

I'm trying to import an excel sheet into an already existing database table.
I'm using the SSIS to do this as the "import/export wizard" has already failed me.

I keep getting these errors:

-[OLE DB Destination [77]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Unspecified error".

-[OLE DB Destination [77]] Error: There was an error with OLE DB Destination.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input].Columns[ConvReturnsPct] on OLE DB Destination.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input]. The column status returned was: "The value violated the integrity constraints for the column.".

-[OLE DB Destination [77]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "OLE DB Destination.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input]" failed because error code 0xC020907D occurred, and the error row disposition on "OLE DB Destination.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input]" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

-[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "OLE DB Destination" (77) failed with error code 0xC0209029 while processing input "OLE DB Destination Input" (90). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

I'm very new to SSIS and I do not know where to go from here. Googling the error codes has turned up fruitless.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Key exception statement:  ""The value violated the integrity constraints for the column.".........its violating referential integrity of the db.  The second Error statement is the only one you need to be concerned with.  The latter usually will always follow the specific error.

Comment: for future reference.  In your package at the task level.  Use a `ExcelSource` and then if it is SQL Server, either use `OLE Db Destination` or 'OLE DB Command' (`OLE DB Command` if using a `StoredProcedure` to import the data.  You might need to add a `Data Conversion` transformation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your column in the table corresponding to ConvReturnsPct, most likely your table does not have the column set up as NULLABLE and your source has some NULLs

Comment: Mmm. On the output of the DFT; I do have "keep null" marked.

Comment: Is the said column Nullable in the table?

Comment: OH! Probably not; any ideas on how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

SSIS errors can be confusing, here's the important one:

`The value violated the integrity constraints for the column`

You have a constraint on a column in your existing table that would be violated if the values from excel were input.  You can transform the problematic data to be compliant, you can send problematic rows elsewhere so that they don't cause your import to fail, or you can ignore the problematic rows and tell the task not to stop running on error.

Comment: Ok, so that the column is formatted as a "number" in excel. Should I change it to general? I'm going to try that.

Comment: Is it going into an `INT` field? The most common problem I encounter is with Excel storing a number as a FLOAT.

Comment: Any mass way to convert the columns to INTs? haha